# Can I get the FAQ ordering via the API?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, sort

StackExchange sites have a feature to order by FAQ, e.g.:

[Screenshot](http://f.cl.ly/items/3V0K1u3R3F0P2L0P380n/Screen%20Shot%202011-09-07%20at%2012.51.26%20PM.png)

This is in fact an ordering by the number of related questions and often produces very nice results.

Can you get that ordering via the API? I tried `sort=related` and `sort=faq` and got invalid sort query errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>No, this is not currently available.</del>

<del>It is currently *not* slated for the next API release either... I'll look into what it would take to get it added though.  If it's not too rough it might make it into V2.</del>

Time was found to implement this, and it's [been deployed](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/faqs-by-tags).